# Simple Lucene Usage?

Tags: java, jar, lucene, command, classpath

(I use Windows 7 64Bit)

I'm trying to use this tutorial:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_1/demo/overview-summary.html

But I'm getting some errors:

- I downloaded the Lucene Framework
- Put the 4 jars in my classpath like it said in the tutorial

`(Classpath=D:\Lucene\lucene-4.8.1\core\lucene-core-4.8.1.jar%D:\Lucene\lucene-4.8.1\queryparser\lucene-queryparser-4.8.1.jar%D:\Lucene\lucene-4.8.1\demo\lucene-demo-4.8.1.jar%D:\Lucene\lucene-4.8.1\analysis\common\lucene-analyzers-common-4.8.1.jar)`

And now I wanted to, for example index the files in Java/src with the command:
java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs D:/Java/src

But it says, that it couldn't find the main class "org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles". Did I set the classpath/environment variable wrong?

Comment: How did you set the classpath? You set the CLASSPATH environmental variable I guess? And it is literally as you put it above? So in stead of the correct ';' separator character you used '%' ?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was that I used '%' instead of  ';' in the classpath. Thanks to Danyal Aytekin.

The Lucene Tutorial worked fine after this.